# String POST Request to Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to implement a simple dashboard with `Flask` that will:

1. Accept a user text input, with a "submit" button. POST this user input to flask.
2. Flask accepts this input, does some stuff to it, then makes a GET request to another API.
3. This GET request returns data and shows it somehow (can just be `console.log` for now)

As an example, with the star wars API:

1. User inputs name of a Star Wars character (assume no spelling errors)
2. Flask reads this input name, and maps it to an ID number, because the [Star Wars API](https://swapi.co) accepts id numbers. Form a GET request to the Star Wars API, to get full character information.
3. For now, we can just `console.log` character information (e.g. "height", "mass", etc.)

What I have now:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
import random
import json

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/form_example", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def form_example():
    if request.method == "POST":
        language = request.form("character_name")
        starwars_dictionary = {"Luke Skywalker":"1", "C-3PO":"2", "R2-D2": "3"}
        # starwars_dictionary is a dictionary with character_name:character_number key-value pairs.
        # GET URL is of the form https://swapi.co/api/people/<character_number>

    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>py-to-JS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Sample Inputs</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Luke Skywalker</li>
        <li>C-3PO</li>
        <li>R2-D2</li>
    </ul>

    <form method="POST">
        Enter Name: <input type="text" name="character_name"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In this current form, when I run the app, it returns "Method not allowed; this method is not allowed for the requested URL".

I'm not sure what I'm missing; it's probably just not wired together properly but I'm not sure what the proper syntax is.

---

Working version after implementing the accepted answer:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
import requests
import random
import json

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/index", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    #character_height = "" # init a default value of empty string...seems unwieldy
    if request.method == "POST":
        character_name = request.form.get("character_name")

        # Map user input to a numbers
        starwars_dictionary = {"Luke Skywalker":"1", "C-3PO":"2", "R2-D2": "3"}
        char_id = starwars_dictionary[character_name]

        url = "https://swapi.co/api/people/"+char_id
        response = requests.get(url)
        response_dict = json.loads(response.text)
        character_height = response_dict["height"]

        return render_template("index.html", character_height=character_height)

    return render_template("index.html")

#@app.route("/form_example", methods=["GET", "POST"])
#def form_example():


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>py-to-JS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Sample Inputs</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Luke Skywalker</li>
        <li>C-3PO</li>
        <li>R2-D2</li>
    </ul>

    <form method="POST" action="/index">
        Enter Name: <input type="text" name="character_name"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
    </form>

    {{ character_height }}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the form is posting to the `/` endpoint, because you didn't declare a form `action`.

Needs to be more like:

```
<form method="POST" action="/form_example">
```

Or if you want to get snazzy and use Jinja's `url_for` function:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('form_example') }}">
```

---

**EDIT:** That said, you could handle this with a single route function:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        language = request.form("character_name")
        starwars_dictionary = {"Luke Skywalker":"1", "C-3PO":"2", "R2-D2": "3"}

        # Logic to query remote API ges here.

    else: # Assume method is GET
        return render_template("index.html")
```

Then make the form action `{{ url_for('index') }}`